# No Vim, I don't want to save changes to a directory

Tags: save, netrw

I frequently use `:e.` to navigate folders and open files in gVim.  But later, when I try to close the session with a `:qall`, I am asked by vim whether or not I want to save changes to the folder(s) I was navigating with netrw.  I couldn't save such changes, even if checked yes.

What do I add to my vimrc to let Vim know that I never want to save changes to a directory?

(I'm using gVim on Windows 7.)

Edit:
I tried this, to no avail:

```
let g:netrw_dirhistmax=0
```

Comment: g:netrw_dirhistmax is used to specify how much history you want netrw to keep about (see :help netrw-u, for example).  It has nothing to do with however you changed a netrw buffer.

Answer (score 4):

You could try setting the `buftype` option. E.g. doing `:set buftype=nofile` should make ignore that buffer.

But I'am wondering how you could modify this buffer, since this should read-protected and not-modifiable.

Comment: I know this is super old, but I thought I'd just add that I tried setting `buftype=nofile` and for some reason that doesn't work either. Not sure what's causing the buffer to get "edited" but it super annoying and I can't find a good fix for this.

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions discussed here: https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar/issues/13

I found this command to work for my setup:

```
autocmd FileType netrw setl bufhidden=delete
```